# Weak convergence of measures on a discrete probability space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

What follows are two different question on weak convergence on a discretization of a probability space and applying some standard probability theory on such a discretization.

Let $(\Omega:=\mathbb{R}_+^d,\mathcal{F}_T)$, $T\in \mathbb{N}$ be a measurable space. We have the canonical processes $X_l(\omega)=\omega_l$, where $\omega\in\Omega$ and $\omega_l$ is the $l$-th coordinate. The time parameter for the processes $X$ is $\{0,\dots,T\}$. The filtration $\mathcal{F}_l$ is generated by $X_0,\dots,X_l$.

We discretize our space, i.e. we let $A_n:=\{\delta k,k=0,\dots\}$ for $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$ and look at $\Omega_n:=A_n^d\subset\Omega$. My first question is of very general nature. Suppose we are given probability measure $\mu_n$ on $\Omega_n$. Note we didn't specify the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega_n$, so please motivate your choice. How can we say that $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight, since they are not defined on the same space. Assuming they are tight, we want to apply Prohorov's theorem to conclude that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ on a subsequence, where $\mu$ should be a probability measure on $\Omega$. Again how can we talk about weak convergence, if the measures are defined on different spaces?

Suppose we are allowed to do the above. 
Let $g$ be a continuous function with $g(x)\le K(1+x^r)$ for some $r>1$  and a constant $K$. We denote with $f_n$ the restriction of $g$ onto $A_n$ and $g_n$ the linear interpolation of $f_n$. Let's assume that

$$\sup_{x\in A_n}\{\frac{|f_n(x)|}{(1+x)^r}\}\le n $$

We clearly have that $g_n$ converges pointwise to $g$. By continuity of $g$ we also have $g(x)=\lim f_n(x_n)$ for any sequence $x_n\to x$. 
We want to make use of the Skorohod representation theorem, in fact we want to establish the following equality

$$ E_\mu[g(X_k)]=\lim E_{\mu_n}[f_n(X_k)] $$

The second question is, why is the above equality true?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

To make your discretization compatible  with the full space, Instead of using point sets, partition your space into finitely many regions, and take the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these finitely many regions.  Then the equivalent notion of random variables with respect to this $\sigma$-algebra is functions which are constant in each region. Then you can talk about measures and functions. Note that for any random variable on the full space, taking the conditional expectation with respect to this discretized $\sigma$-algebra gives you a random variable (averages the function on each region) which you can think of as a discretization of the random variable which converges to the original random variable as your discretization becomes finer and finer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But actually in the paper, they are using this kind of discretization. So I would like to understand it with this assumption. And what about the equality at the end of my question?